# svn client over ssh

Tags: svn, version-control, ssh, tortoisesvn, collabnet

We currently have:

1. a server installed Collabnet Subversion Edge used as a SVN server, I have full control to this server.
2. a TortoiseSVN installed on my local machine.
3. a server (called it FileSERVER) that I only have SSH
   access. and this server doesn't have SVN client installed.

Question is how can I commit file on FileSERVER to SVN SERVER without install SVN client on FileSERVER? Is it be able to use the TortoiseSVN client through SSH connection?

Thank you very much, waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try software like [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) (ex. SftpDrive) or [SSH Drive](http://sshdrive.com/index.php). They will create a drive on your Windows machine, mapped to a home directory of your FileSERVER account, so you can create working copy with TortoiseSVN and commit it. (I did not try this myself.)

Or you could just copy that file to Windows machine via Sftp every time you need to commit it.

Comment: I tried SSH Drive, I successfully get mapped to my local as Network Drive. But, I got access when write. However, if I just connect use ftp client, I can read and write. Any ideas?

Comment: Updates, ExpanDrive works perfectly. However it is not free. Thank you very much.